# Feedback on a proof regarding periodic functions.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

[image]

Hi I was wondering if my proof makes sense or if I have some flaws in logic or mistakes I need to take care of..

**Question 5.**

**a.**

$f\:'\left(T\right)=\lim \:_{h\to \:o}\frac{f\left(T+h\right)-f\left(T\right)}{h}=\lim\: _{h\to o}\frac{f\left(0+h\right)-f\left(0\right)}{h}=f\:'\left(0\right)$

**b.**

Note that since $f$ is differentiable on $[0,T]$, it is also continuous on $[0,T]$.

We know that $ f(0)=f(T)$ for every $x∈R$, therefore by Rolle's theorem there exist a point $0 < x_{1} < T $ such that $f'(x_{1}) = 0$.

Note that $f$ is also differential and continuous on $[x_{1},x_{1}+T]$, therefore since we have
$f(x_{1}) = f(x_{1}+T)$

by Rolle's theorem there exist a point $x_{1} < x_{2} < (x_{1}+T)$ such that $f'(x_{2})=0$.

We have two cases, $0 < x_{1} < x_{2} ≤ T < (x_{1}+T)$ or $0 < x_{1} < T < x_{2} < (x_{1}+T)$

**Case 1**: $x_{1} < x_{2} ≤ T$

In this case $x_{2}∈[0,T]$ so we have  $f'(x_{2})=f'(x_{1})=0$ such that $x_{1} ≠ x_{2}$

**Case 2**: $T < x_{2} < (x_{1}+T)$

In this case $f(x_{2}) = f(x_{2}-T) = 0$, and $0 < (x_{2}-T) < x_{1} < T$

Therefore we have $(x_{2}-T) ∈ [0,T]$ and $f(x_{2}-T) = f(x_{1}) = 0$ such that $(x_{2}-T)≠x_{1}$.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: The first is good. For the second it might be simpler to note that $f$ has  a $\min,\max$ on $[0,T]$ (and hence on $\mathbb{R}$) and if they are the same then $f$ is a constant, otherwise they are distinct.